# How can I replicate the process sklearn calculates the posterior probabilities?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

I have a question pertaining to scikit-learn methods.

Can I get the same probabilities obtained with predict_log_proba() by hand calculating the likelihoods and prior obtained with feature_log_prob_ and class_log_prior_?

After obtaining likelhoods and prior, I summed the likelihoods and prior in an attempt to get posterior but the values given by predict_log_proba() are different.

Comment: This will depend on the model implementation, which model are you using?

Comment: @Gijs, my apology, I missed out the model!! I am using multinomial.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by building my own MultinomialNB and understood how posteriors are calculated.

Although I could still not replicate the process by using sklearn, building it helped answer alot.

If anyone would like to know the detail of calculation, I post my code below. Hope it helps.

import numpy as np

class multinomialNB:
    def **init**(self, alpha=1):
        self.alpha = alpha

```
def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
    m, n = X_train.shape
    self._classes = np.unique(y_train)
    n_classes = len(self._classes)

    # init: Prior & Likelihood
    self._priors = np.zeros(n_classes)
    self._likelihoods = np.zeros((n_classes, n))

    # Get Prior and Likelihood
    for idx, c in enumerate(self._classes):
        X_train_c = X_train[c == y_train]
        self._priors[idx] = X_train_c.shape[0] / m 
        self._likelihoods[idx, :] = ((X_train_c.sum(axis=0)) + self.alpha) / (np.sum(X_train_c.sum(axis=0) + self.alpha))


def predict(self, X_test):
    return [self._predict(x_test) for x_test in X_test]

def _predict(self, x_test):
    # Calculate posterior for each class
    posteriors = []
    for idx, c in enumerate(self._classes):
        prior_c = np.log(self._priors[idx])
         # You need to add piece of code that filters out the features presented or not for the test sample
        likelihoods_c = self.calc_likelihood(self._likelihoods[idx,:], x_test)
        posteriors_c = np.sum(likelihoods_c) + prior_c
        posteriors.append(posteriors_c)

    return self._classes[np.argmax(posteriors)]

def calc_likelihood(self, cls_likeli, x_test):
    return np.log(cls_likeli) * x_test

def score(self, X_test, y_test):
    y_pred = self.predict(X_test)
    return np.sum(y_pred == y_test)/len(y_test)
```